# How to compute the mean of a list of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

I am continuing my journey in python and would like to find the most elegant/optimal way to compute the mean of a `list` of `dataframes`.

I have written the below function, assuming the data frames are series.

Here is the code below:

```
def f(list_of_df):
     sum, length = 0, 0
     for i in list_of_df:
         sum += i.sum()
         length += len(i)
     return sum / length
```

This works, but is there a better way, more elegant, more optimal?

Comment: [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a built-in python function (that could be useful for your problem). The way you did in the example overwrote the function to be something else. Consider a different name for that variable, like `sum_`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also do :

```
#shapes should be same
df_concat = pd.concat((df1,df2,df3,df4))

df_concat.mean()
```

or maybe

```
df_concat.groupby(level=0).mean()
df_concat.groupby(level=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), it it generally pretty fast:

```py
import numpy as np

np.concatenate(list_of_df).mean()
```

This assumes that `list_of_df` is a list of pandas Series